# JAVA SQL Database Locked Error

Tags: java, database, locks

I am having trouble running my code. Every time I enter user information to sign up a user i get the the error:
`java.sql.SQLException: database is locked`

Comment: This seems like too big a chunk of code for someone to reproduce your problem with. I suggest you narrow it down to a question about a few specific lines first.

Comment: Many thanks, removed some code and some extra insight on the problem

Comment: This many levels of `if` nesting is usually bad practice and creates hard to maintain code.  Can you try combining these multiple nested `if`s with `&&` and `||` logic?  You may find your bug when refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely a result of incomplete operations you have started and not finished elsewhere against the database, such as transactions you haven't committed. You should close all resources. Something somewhere didn't get closed properly, causing the lock to stay on.

Answer (score 0):

Result of your query() method - the result set - is never closed.

It is helpful to tell which database are you using, since they have different ways of handling locks.

Also, you may wish to add simple debug points, like "System.out.println" to each of your database operations. This helps you to see the flow of database statements which end up with a lock.

Once you have an exception, you shall keep the exception call stack. This helps to identify on which SQL operation did you get the lock - and helps focusing on the real problem.

(May I suggest considering MVC or a light DDD to isolate gui and db code to keep your code clean, and *avoiding* doing any database operation from the event handling thread since that will eventually introduce lockups on your gui, once you get as big as spotify. :))

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. I added the close for the replySet - 'reply.close(); ', under the line in database file 'reply = stmn.executeQuery(sqlString);' 
But i get the error : 
    Mar 13, 2016 7:07:53 PM account.FXMLController_Register signupBtnClicked

    SEVERE: null

    java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed

Comment: that is not correct, you shall close the result set *after* you have processed the reply. I.e. in addContactDetails and addSubscriptions, ensure that rsContact is closed *after* you read out the response from the result set.